# Why CSS Not Being Applied?

Tags: css

I have a News section on the "Home" page of a subsite, https://galvestonecon.prod.govaccess.org/home-econdev that is currently in development. I have assigned this home page the class of **econdev** (short for Economic Development - a subsite of our main Galveston County website) to be able to assign styles and JavaScript to the page.

I am trying to **text-align:center** the "Continue To Blog" link at the bottom of the list of test News items but it's not picking up that CSS.  I know the selector (**.econdev a.box_bottomlink**) is correct because my red border is showing up, but the text is still stuck to the left side.  I feel like this should be easy but I've tried everything, the various ways of centering items on the page and nothing makes it budge.  I don't have access to change the HTML because I am working with a limited SDK and the Support team for our vendor will not help me.  I hope I've provided enough info here.  Please let me know if more is needed.  The main relevant markup is:

```css
/* CSS for Home Econ Dev */

body.front_end_body;
.sitewrapper;
* {
  font-size: 100% !important;
}


/*Removing elements from template that exist on main site - color gradients, CTA buttons, etc. - home template but not wanted on EconDev site */

.econdev .home_item4,
.econdev .home_item3,
.econdev .home_buttons:before {
  display: none !important;
}

.econdev .content_area,
.econdev a.box_bottomlink,
.econdev .home_item2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  !important;
}


/*GC Is Real*/

.econdev .home_item2 td p {
  margin: 0 3em 0 0;
}


/*How Can We Help Section */

.howwecanhelp {
  flex-basis: 80%;
}

.econdev .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*Recent News*/

.econdev ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  !important;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.econdev .home_item2 li.hasimage a.news-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.econdev .home_item2 li.hasimage a.news-item div.item_info {
  justify-content;
  center;
}

.econdev .home_item2 li.hasimage img {
  width: 150px;
  !important;
  height: 150px;
  !important;
  padding: 5px;
  margin 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.econdev a.news-item p {
  justify-content;
  right;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.econdev a.box_bottomlink {
  margin: 0 auto;
  !important;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a class="box_bottomlink" href="/blog">Continue to Blog</a> FULL HTML for the News Widget

<!--!!WidgetStart, vi-orderdata="0"  vi-hideonmobile="false" vi-widgetinstancedata="1583"WidgetStart!!-->
<div id='widget_1583_2927_1882' class='content_area normal_content_area clearfix  '>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Recent News</h2>
</div>
<!--!!WidgetEnd-->

<!--!!WidgetStart, vi-orderdata="0"  vi-hideonmobile="false" vi-widgetinstancedata="1584"WidgetStart!!-->

<!--stopindex-->

<!--<div class="news_container">-->
<!--<h2 class="widget_header">Recent News</h2>-->
<ul>


  <li class="hasimage">
    <a href="/Home/Components/News/News/513/955" class="news-item">
      <div class="image_frame"><img alt="News Item Test 1 - Title" src="/home/showpublishedimage/2098/637715605434130000" /> </div>
      <div class="item_info">
        <p class="box_item_title">News Item Test 1 - Title</p>
        <p class="box_item_summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in turpis sed mauris facilisis hendrerit non nec ante. Mauris ornare eu lorem nec tempus. Nullam non nunc sed velit ullamcorper accumsan. Integer vitae enim at lacus molestie viverra.
          Vestibulum euismod finibus arcu quis vulputate. Pro</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hasimage">
    <a href="/Home/Components/News/News/515/955" class="news-item">
      <div class="image_frame"><img alt="News Item Test 2 - Title" src="/home/showpublishedimage/2774/637720681345270000" /> </div>
      <div class="item_info">
        <p class="box_item_title">News Item Test 2 - Title</p>
        <p class="box_item_summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in turpis sed mauris facilisis hendrerit non nec ante. Mauris ornare eu lorem nec tempus. Nullam non nunc sed velit ullamcorper accumsan. Integer vitae enim at lacus molestie viverra.
          Vestibulum euismod finibus arcu quis vulputate. Pro</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<a href="/blog" class="box_bottomlink">Continue to Blog</a>
<!--</div>-->

<!--startindex-->
<!--!!WidgetEnd-->
```

Comment: Could you check to see if the Snippet with the HTML and CSS together accurately reproduces your problem? If not, please edit that combined Snippet to ensure that it does so, and then strip out any irrelevant material, since all we need is an "*[mcve]*" sample of your code. That said, if your CSS isn't being applied, have you checked that it's being loaded by your browser? If you set `background-color: red;` to the `body` element (with no other modifiers) does it get applied? If not, then for some reason it's not being loaded, if it is applied then it seems your selectors are perhaps wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the html use nth-of-type() in your css.  also change the display to block

```css
/* CSS for Home Econ Dev */

body.front_end_body;
.sitewrapper;
* {
  font-size: 100% !important;
}


/*Removing elements from template that exist on main site - color gradients, CTA buttons, etc. - home template but not wanted on EconDev site */

.econdev .home_item4,
.econdev .home_item3,
.econdev .home_buttons:before {
  display: none !important;
}

.econdev .content_area,
.econdev a.box_bottomlink,
.econdev .home_item2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  !important;
}


a:nth-of-type(2) {
   text-align:center;
   color:green;   
   display:block;
}

/*GC Is Real*/

.econdev .home_item2 td p {
  margin: 0 3em 0 0;
}


/*How Can We Help Section */

.howwecanhelp {
  flex-basis: 80%;
}

.econdev .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*Recent News*/

.econdev ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  !important;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.econdev .home_item2 li.hasimage a.news-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.econdev .home_item2 li.hasimage a.news-item div.item_info {
  justify-content;
  center;
}

.econdev .home_item2 li.hasimage img {
  width: 150px;
  !important;
  height: 150px;
  !important;
  padding: 5px;
  margin 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.econdev a.news-item p {
  justify-content;
  right;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 0 1em 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.econdev a.box_bottomlink {
  margin: 0 auto;
  !important;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<a class="box_bottomlink" href="/blog">Continue to Blog</a> FULL HTML for the News Widget

<!--!!WidgetStart, vi-orderdata="0"  vi-hideonmobile="false" vi-widgetinstancedata="1583"WidgetStart!!-->
<div id='widget_1583_2927_1882' class='content_area normal_content_area clearfix  '>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Recent News</h2>
</div>
<!--!!WidgetEnd-->

<!--!!WidgetStart, vi-orderdata="0"  vi-hideonmobile="false" vi-widgetinstancedata="1584"WidgetStart!!-->

<!--stopindex-->

<!--<div class="news_container">-->
<!--<h2 class="widget_header">Recent News</h2>-->
<ul>


  <li class="hasimage">
    <a href="/Home/Components/News/News/513/955" class="news-item">
      <div class="image_frame"><img alt="News Item Test 1 - Title" src="/home/showpublishedimage/2098/637715605434130000" /> </div>
      <div class="item_info">
        <p class="box_item_title">News Item Test 1 - Title</p>
        <p class="box_item_summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in turpis sed mauris facilisis hendrerit non nec ante. Mauris ornare eu lorem nec tempus. Nullam non nunc sed velit ullamcorper accumsan. Integer vitae enim at lacus molestie viverra.
          Vestibulum euismod finibus arcu quis vulputate. Pro</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hasimage">
    <a href="/Home/Components/News/News/515/955" class="news-item">
      <div class="image_frame"><img alt="News Item Test 2 - Title" src="/home/showpublishedimage/2774/637720681345270000" /> </div>
      <div class="item_info">
        <p class="box_item_title">News Item Test 2 - Title</p>
        <p class="box_item_summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in turpis sed mauris facilisis hendrerit non nec ante. Mauris ornare eu lorem nec tempus. Nullam non nunc sed velit ullamcorper accumsan. Integer vitae enim at lacus molestie viverra.
          Vestibulum euismod finibus arcu quis vulputate. Pro</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>


<a href="/blog" class="box_bottomlink">Continue to Blog</a>

<!--</div>-->

<!--startindex-->
<!--!!WidgetEnd-->
```

Comment: Yes,  Just for completeness, the issue here is that an `<a>` tag is an inline tag, not a block tag.  You are aligning the contents of the `<a>` tag, but the tag's area is just large enough to hold the contents, so the alignment is irrelevant.

Comment: thanks, but as I reread the op's question it appears he can't change the html, so I updated the snippet

Comment: Sorry, I was not critiquing your answer, I was just explaining it.

Comment: Dave Thomas, thanks, but as I mentioned in my initial post, I do indeed have a red border and that is working so I know my selector is correct.  I'll definitely try the nth-of-type though, thank you!

Comment: Tim Roberts, thank you for explaining.  I know anchors are inline but I was thinking that was okay since I'm trying to get the comment to be on the same line as the image.  But I see now what you mean that the alignment is not relevant as a result.  That helps me understand better.  I appreciate it!